# Coupling between (web)controls in ASP.NET 4

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I was wondering is there is possible to couple together two web controls (ascx) so they would react on each other changes. I have in mind scenario similar to validation controls, where (in validation control) I select available control to be validated.

Now I would like to do same in my web controls. I have control A and control B. Scenario is that when I change something in control A, control B will be updated. Iam creating controls A and B as WebControls (ascx). I would like (on design time) put two controls (A and B) on webform, and select in control A coupling with control B, so when some event occurs in control A, control A checks if control B is not null and "does things to it".

Is this applicable for WebControl type controls ?! I assume that I should use some attributes on properties of control A, but where to store control B in control A ?! ViewState and Context.Items require controls to be serializable...

Any ideas ?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass the control id from one control to another. Then you can force the coupled controls to inherit some base class and use FindControl to get an instance of each other. I believe this is how databound controls work with the DataSource controls.

Comment: Yep, It worked thx! (I will mark this as an answer in few minutes). But one more question --- isn't such way slow ?! To find my control I did not use "FindControl" (control B is in Update Panel etc etc), but I wrote simple "RecursiveFindControl" ... Isn't this "quite slow" ?!

Comment: Sure it is slower than setting it directly but it should work in most cases. ASP.NET traverses the control tree several times during the page lifecycle and does many more things. One more traversal would not impact the performance too much. Of course be sure to cache the reference to the control instead of search for it every time the property is accessed.